# Magento USPS - What if product weight is not available?

Tags: magento, usps

I have one query for USPS shipping method in Magento. If I don’t know and i don’t enter the weight of the product in magento, then how USPS will count the cost?

I want where if total amount to pay is over $50 then FREE Shipping will go else it will show fix $5 rate for USPS. I almost have same weight small products so I don't want cost to be calculated. I just want user to know that via USPS, their parcel will come and for that they need to pay more $5 charge.

Can anyone give me idea for what I want to achieve? Any tip will be great help.

Maria

Answer (score 0):

you can create a extension for shipping query that include some shipping carrier of DHL UPS and more.
1.create a SOAP for get data from MySQL
2.declare & create for magento on checkout.
example:
www.chinabuye.com

I was customize shipping fee on this site